# How do I enable CentOS Repositories on RHEL Red Hat?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, repository

I'm in the process of purchasing a RHEL license. In the meantime, I'd like to utilize CentOS 7 repos on my RHEL 7. I created a /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo file in the /etc/yum.repos.d directory but I don't know how to move past that. Most of the information I found online either points to fedora repos or is referring to CentOS 5. Below is something I found online and copy pasted onto my centos.repo file. Thank you.

```
[centos]
name=CentOS $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/centos/7/os/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=updates
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
priority=1

#packages used/produced in the build but not released
[addons]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Addons
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=addons
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/addons/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
priority=1

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=extras
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
priority=1

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=centosplus
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
priority=2

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=contrib
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
priority=2
```

Answer (score 26):

Delete this centos.repo (or change enabled=0 for all) and Create a new repository centos1.repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` with the content:

```
[centos]
name=CentOS-7
baseurl=http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/centos/7/os/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/centos/7/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Then run

```
yum repolist
```

Now check if you can install any package like

```
yum install nmap -y
```

Done!!!

Comment: It would be nice if OP ticked this as an accepted answer to let those of us who are searching, know that this is a solution.

Comment: This is the way to go. So much win

Answer (score 3):

You can use *repo*-file from *CentOS*, but need to prepare it:

1. Replace `$releasever` inside this file with the appropriate release number (e.g. **7** for *RHEL-7*):

   ```
   sed -i 's/$releasever/7/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
   ```
2. Download key:

   ```
   curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7 >/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
   ```

   or change inside *repo*-file `gpgkey`'s:

   ```
   gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
   ```